# Indexes In Sql server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL server
What is the difference between Index and clustered Indexes ? 
and are PKs clustered Indexes by default ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SQL Server and Oracle:**

There are clustered and nonclustered indexes. A clustered index is a special type of index that reorders the way records in the table are physically stored. Therefore table can have only one clustered index. The leaf nodes of a clustered index contain the data pages.

A nonclustered index is a special type of index in which the logical order of the index does not match the physical stored order of the rows on disk. The leaf node of a nonclustered index does not consist of the data pages. Instead, the leaf nodes contain index rows.

PKs CAN be clustered by default, but if you have already created a clustered index.  Then it may not be.

Answers obtained from: [FAQ: clustered vs nonclustered indexes](http://www.mssqlcity.com/FAQ/General/clustered_vs_nonclustered_indexes.htm) & [Geekinterview: clustered index and nonclustered index](http://www.geekinterview.com/talk/11589-clustered-index-and-nonclustered-index.html) & [MSDN: PK Constraint vs. Clustered/Unique Index Declaration](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/086923c4-92c5-4d85-9cea-578dd097b118)

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, there's no such thing as a clustered index.  One can create an index-organized table, where the rows are physically stored in a B-tree structure according to the values of the primary key - but that's not a clustered index.